# ¿Cómo agregar decimales a un número completo de tipo String en Java? es posible?

Tags: java, string, double

Tengo un tipo de dato String con el valor **23355** y quiero mostrarlo con dos decimales, seria a asi **233.55**, trate de hacer lo siguiente pero no me lo muestra como lo requiero, lo muestra asi
**23355.00**

como puedo hacer para que me lo muestre como lo requiero

```html
String valor = datos.getValorPorcentaje().replaceFirst("^0*", "");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String resultado = df.format(Double.parseDouble(valor));
```

Comment: Y necesitas mantenerlo como String, entonces? Todos los valores posibles tienen el mismo formato? Vienen XXXYY con dos Y que son los decimales?

Comment: De preferencia mantenerlo con String, pero sino lo cambio a Double , pero como quedaria para mostrarlo asi como lo requiero?

Comment: Haces un substring a `valor.length - 2` hasta `valor.length`, le concatenas el punto a la primera parte y a continuación concatenas los dos últimos dígitos. Y ya tienes el string como tú quieres. Basicamente, algo así: `valor = valor.substring(0, valor.length-2) + "." + valor.substring(valor.length-2);`

Comment: 23355 "con dos decimales" es 23355.00. 233.55 **es otro número** que, por ejemplo, puedes calcular haciendo 23355/100, por ejemplo (cuidado con no hace división de enteros). No confundas los números, porque si no tu jefe pasará a pagarte 10.00€ en vez de 1000€.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si siempre vas querer tomar los 2 último caracteres del String para convertirlo en  la parte decimal, puedes hacer uso de `/` y `%` .
Primero conviertes el `String` a `int` para que puedas hallar la división y el residuo.
Te dejo el código.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="233555";
        int a=Integer.parseInt(s);
        int entero= a/100;
        int decimal=a%100;
        double fraccion=entero+(double)decimal/100;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        
        System.out.println("El número es: "+a);
        System.out.println("Parte entera: "+entero);
        System.out.println("Parte decimal: "+decimal);
        System.out.println("Fraccion es: "+df.format(fraccion));
        
    }
```

La segunda forma de hacer, en realidad es la misma idea que la anterior pero quitando variables innecesarios.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="233555";       
        double fraccion=Double.parseDouble(s)/100;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println("Fraccion es: " + df.format(fraccion));       
    }
```

Comment: Yo soy muy vago. No me gusta escribir 5 líneas cuando lo puedo hacer con una. Además, para qué el parseo a `double` cuando desde el principio podrías usar `Double.parseDouble(s)`? Es más, si usas un double y lo divides `doble/100`, te ahorras andar con residuos... cualquier número entero dividido entre 100 dará un número con dos decimales. El único problema que puede tener es que esos decimales sean ambos 0, pero eso ya es cosa de representarlo, no de guardarlo. De hecho, haces una cosa muy rara al calcular `fraccion`, dividiendo decimal/100 cuando decimal ya es el resto de esa misma división!

Comment: @Benito-B Si hago uso de varias líneas es para hacer entender mejor los pasos sin menospreciar la inteligencia de los demás, con lo de ``Double.parseDouble(s)`` si tienes razón no es necesario el ``Integer.parseInte(s)`` al inicio.  y lo de dividir entre 100 el decimal si es necesario, porque la variable que tiene el número decimal es un número de 2 dígitos y si lo quiero sumar con parte entera se tiene que dividir entre 100. De todas formas edito mi respuesta con los cambios convenientes.

Comment: Y el summum ya es `double fraccion=Double.parseDouble(s)/100; System.out.println("Fraccion es: " + df.format(fraccion));` Una única línea igualmente